# Prism 2 for Silverlight with Unity - 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException'

Tags: silverlight, unity-container, prism

I am using Unity with Silverlight and Prism 2. On my laptop (running Vista 32) I am seeing the following error in the output window in VS.NET 2008 SP1 - which I think is being caught internally by Unity.

A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity

On my desktop machine (running Vista 64) with the same codebase but I am not seeing the same error.

I first discovered that there was a problem on the laptop because the app (that uses Prism 2) I have some events being published and the subscribers are not being notified. The desktop machine is working great with Prism events.

Any idea what could be wrong?
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how to turn it off is next:

- In VS IDE go to Debug\Exceptions menu (or press Ctrl+Alt+E)
- Uncheck the Thrwon check box beside the "Common Language Runtime exceptions"

As for why it is happening, I guess you  [already got that](http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=51337) :)

Comment: That's a cop-out. There are ways of stopping the exception being thrown in the first place - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2873767/1016