# How can I extend a Unity catalog at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-container, app-config, ioc-container, unity2.0

I want to map most of my interfaces to concrete classes in my app.config file. However, I would like to register some interfaces to the same Unity catalog at runtime. I tried the code below, but it gives me a *`SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`*

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

UnityConfigurationSection configSection =
    (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
configSection.Containers.Default.Configure(container);

container.RegisterInstance<IInterface>(new ConcreteObject());
```

How can I register an object at runtime in a Unity catalog initialized from app.config?

I am using the Unity version (2.0) that ships with Prism4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem, but not technically an error, with registering unity objects. Change your regsitration to this:

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, ConcreteObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

That should fix your problem.

That exception gets thrown because of this:

[Can Unity be made to not throw SynchronizationLockException all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873767/can-unity-be-made-to-not-throw-synchronizationlockexception-all-the-time)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but how do I pass in the object instance?

Comment: That should create the instance for you when you ask for it.

Comment: yes, but I do not want it to new up a new instance. I want it to return an instance I register with the container at runtime.