# Internal exceptions are thrown not in my code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I use NHibernate and Enterprise Library for my project. I do some calls like `new UnityContainerConfigurator(_container)`, `_container.RegisterInstance(instance)`, and `var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()` which causing VS to stop as they throw internal exceptions (first two throws SynchronizationLockException and the last one - BindingFailure).

If I press F5, it skips this exception and continue running, so I assume these have happened internally in the libraries and were handled. But I have no idea why VS keeps notifying me about these.

I have "Enable Just My Code" option turned on. As I understood if this option is turned on, these exceptions should not interrupt the execution as they are internal to the libraries I use, but this is not so in practice.

At Exception window (Ctrl+Alt+E) I have all exceptions marked as "Thrown". But that is actually what I need - I want to be notified for any exception happened **in my code**, but not the code from the libraries. I do not want to unset this configuration or filter the exceptions bothering me and check them out.

Any ideas how to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: "Just My Code" only affects whet code the debugger steps into - it does not filter the exceptions that it stops on as far as I know.

Comment: @DStanley Any other option I should look into?

Comment: The only options I know of to filter exception and to check on/off individual exception types.

Answer (score 1):

From Top Menu, Select Debug menu item; then select Exceptions. Make sure that Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked.

And for more information about `SynchronizationLockException` and Unity Container, refer to [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873767/can-unity-be-made-to-not-throw-synchronizationlockexception-all-the-time).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. They are checked. And this is exactly what causing the problem. But I do not want to uncheck them - this check is quite useful. As for the link to the SO question, thank - this one is quite interesting. It is not solving the problem I have, but I definitely have to look at that more.